# jQuery code conflicting with submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code on my website:

```
    $('input[type="submit"], a').not('[target=_blank]').click(function(){
        var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
        if(!bad) {
            $(".load-overlay").show();
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

This is supposed to show a loading screen on valid links; valid links are links without javascript in the href, or with # in the href. Also valid links are without target=_blank attributes.

It's doing its job but it's conflicting with the submits buttons.

The loading screen (`.load-overlay`) doesn't show on submit buttons, but it's defined in the code. What's the matter with this? I have no errors in the console.

Comment: have you tried console.logging, bad, and the values of this.href.lastIndexOf('#') and this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0?

Comment: @wateriswet Yes, but can't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: And bad always evaluates to false?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because an input does not have a href attribute. Because of that a TypeError Exception will be thrown, when clicking on a submit button. You have to check, if this.href exists, before using it.

change

```
var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
```

to

```
var bad = typeof this.href !== "undefined" && (this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0);
```

**Edit**:

This solves the problem with your loading screen not showing up when clicking a submit button, but for future changes it is good to know, that this.href may return a different value than you expect.

`this.href` returns the full parsed url, the link directs to. If you have a link with a relative url, this value is different from the "href"-attribute in your HTML. To get the exact value of the HTML attribute, use jQuery Function .attr or JavaScript function getAttribute.

Example: `<a href="/home">Home</a>`

In this case `this.href` is `http://yourdomain.com/home`, but `this.getAttribute("href")` is `/home`.

For your current implementation this is irrelevant. But maybe you want to check in the future if the href attribute STARTS with an # or if there is an url to a different site before the #.

Comment: This isn't the right answer, I got you J.Doe, just give me a minute.